# How to update a key of an object of an array element using v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

I am creating a form whose questions are fetched from an api, so i want to grab there answers in different input fields for answers. For this I am creating a response array(`length >=noOfQuestions`) to hold response and prefilled the array with the format I want to store answers. Now I am using `v-model` to update the respective key like for `Question1 update the response[0]`, `for question2 update response[1]`, but when i am updating response for one index other index are also updating.

See the demo https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuetify-tutorial-forked-314r8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark (see the AppFooter.vue)

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong here , or any other method to do this
using vue@2 and vuetify

```
<template>
  <v-footer height="auto">
    <v-card flat tile class="indigo white--text text-xs-center">
      <v-flex v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
        <span class="subheading"> Q{{ index + 1 }}. {{ question.text }} </span>
        <v-text-field
          v-if="question.answerType === 'text'"
          v-model="response[index].answer"
          class="mt-2"
          placeholder="Enter Your Answer"
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-radio-group
          v-if="question.answerType === 'scq'"
          :column="false"
          v-model="response[index].answer"
        >
          <v-radio
            v-for="item in question.options"
            :key="item"
            :label="item"
            :value="item"
          ></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
        <v-flex d-flex v-if="question.answerType === 'mcq'">
          <v-checkbox
            v-for="(item, i) in question.options"
            v-model="response[index].answer"
            :key="i"
            :label="item"
            :value="item"
            multiple
          ></v-checkbox>
        </v-flex>
      </v-flex>
    </v-card>
  </v-footer>
</template>

<script>
const format = {
  answer: "",
  options: "",
};
export default {
  data: () => ({
    questions: [
      {
        text: "Question 1",
        answerType: "text",
        details: "Question 1 details",
      },
      {
        text: "Question 2",
        answerType: "scq",
        options: ["a", "b"],
        details: "Question 1 details",
      },
      {
        text: "Question 3",
        answerType: "mcq",
        options: ["aa", "bb"],
        details: "Question 1 details",
      },
    ],
    response: Array.from(Array(3), () => format),
  }),
  watch: {
    response: {
      handler: function () {
        console.log(this.response);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make the `response` part of each `question`, rather than using a separate array. The expansion of `format` creates a new response object for each question:

```js
data: () => ({
  questions: [
    {
      text: "Question 1",
      answerType: "text",
      details: "Question 1 details",
      response: { ...format },
    },
    {
      text: "Question 2",
      answerType: "scq",
      options: ["a", "b"],
      details: "Question 1 details",
      response: { ...format },
    },
    {
      text: "Question 3",
      answerType: "mcq",
      options: ["aa", "bb"],
      details: "Question 1 details",
      response: { ...format },
    },
  ],
}),
```

In the HTML template, use `v-model = "question.response.answer"`

Comment: this can be one way, but I don't want to modify the format of the questions array. But why this is not working as I am updating response at particular index so what could be the issue . Any other way without editing the question format @J. Titus